# How can I get the ID of an element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<div id="test"></div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert($('#test').id);
  });  
</script>
```

Why doesn't the above work, and how should I do this?

Comment: Getting the ID of an element that has been selected via its ID? o.O

Comment: Sample code. I'm working on an event trigger that uses "this" and I need to know what triggered the event, and independently track how many times each element is triggered. Building a sample with "this" will be far too large.

Comment: Here ya go: https://gist.github.com/ykessler/52f8af9877a216a9169c9704b57ebf9e

Answer (score 2771, accepted):

The jQuery way:

```
$('#test').attr('id')
```

In your example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($('#test').attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Or through the DOM:

```
$('#test').get(0).id;
```

or even :

```
$('#test')[0].id;
```

and reason behind usage of `$('#test').get(0)` in JQuery or even `$('#test')[0]` is that `$('#test')` is a JQuery selector and **returns an array() of results** not a single element by its default functionality

an alternative for DOM selector in jquery is

```
$('#test').prop('id')
```

which is different from `.attr()` and `$('#test').prop('foo')` grabs the specified DOM `foo` property, while `$('#test').attr('foo')` grabs the specified HTML `foo` attribute and you can find more details about differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).

Comment: It amazes me each time that jQuery does not have a shortcut for this like `$('#test').id()`.

Comment: It would be rarely useful because id's are typically hard-coded into the HTML and JS. When you write JS, you already know the ID of some element, so you write that ID to retrieve the element. You rarely need to get the ID of an element programmatically.

Comment: Make that 164969 times.  Plus now I'm here.  I have code that initializes forms.  A few of the forms have special requirements.  I _could_ look for specific form elements to decide what to do, but I think identifying the form - thus the id of the form - is the most logical and surefire way.

Comment: JSF, for example, generates IDs for elements (if not defined).

Comment: Backbone catches all form submissive events, they can be thrown by any element -- you won't know the .id().

Comment: @daniel1426 I for example need it because i create a structure of nested divs dynamically from json data. it's very usefull then if you can just build things like $('.div-structure').on('click', function(){ doStuffWith(**$(this).attr('id')**); });

Comment: Why would I need to get an element's id? Because I have an event handler attached to a class of elements, and I need to know which particular element triggered the event. I hope I'm doing this right.

Comment: Why `$('[id^="begin"]').attr("id")` returns concatenated ids?

Comment: I've created a request in GitHub .. maybe something will be done :) https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3413

Comment: @RickyLevi doubt it, the JQuery gods (snobs) do not see any value in the ID or Name values.  Guess the thought is that the selector approach could return multiple possible elements and therefore, no easy way to extract the ID, or IDs.  If it is an `array`, then return an `array` of IDs otherwise it is a singleton and return the `id`.

Comment: @GoldBishop yep, they've closed it :D

Comment: @RickyLevi well i posted a simple solution, below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42144268/659246.  Wasn't that hard to develop for my low level of skill.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/ `$('#test')[0].id;` or `$('#tes[0]').id;` or `$('#test').get(0).id;`

Comment: I got the point, but the example is a bit confusing, you are using id to get id? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The fact that `$(this.hash)` exists is justification enough to have something like `$(this.id)`, or may be it's just wishful thinking.

Comment: jQuery is mainy used for its $('#element_id') and $('class tag'). Therefore it should be at worse about 200 bytes long code, NOT 97000!

Comment: Opps.. make that 1,122,603 times.. :P

Comment: as of JAN2018, prop() is prefered to attr()

Comment: @comte why is that?

Answer (score 95):

`$('selector').attr('id')` will return the id of the first matched element. [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

If your matched set contains more than one element, you can use the conventional `.each` [iterator](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to return an array containing each of the ids:

```
var retval = []
$('selector').each(function(){
  retval.push($(this).attr('id'))
})
return retval
```

Or, if you're willing to get a little grittier, you can avoid the wrapper and use the `.map` [shortcut](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

```
return $('.selector').map(function(index,dom){return dom.id})
```

Comment: BTW, I think `retval.push($(this).attr('id'))` can be written `retval.push(this.id)`

Comment: If you need an attribute of HMTL5 data-** then use something like this: 
`return $('.selector').map(function(i, dom){ return $(dom).attr('data-id'); })`

Comment: The .selector property was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and is only maintained to the extent needed for supporting .live() in the jQuery Migrate plugin.  The property was never a reliable indicator of the selector that could be used to obtain the set of elements currently contained in the jQuery set where it was a property, since subsequent traversal methods may have changed the set.

Answer (score 43):

`id` is a property of an html `Element`. However, when you write `$("#something")`, it returns a jQuery object that wraps the matching DOM element(s). To get the first matching DOM element back, call `get(0)`

```
$("#test").get(0)
```

On this native element, you can call id, or any other native DOM property or function.

```
$("#test").get(0).id
```

That's the reason why `id` isn't working in your code.

Alternatively, use jQuery's `attr` method as other answers suggest to get the `id` attribute of the first matching element.

```
$("#test").attr("id")
```

Answer (score 27):

Above answers are great, but as jquery evolves.. so you can also do:

```
var myId = $("#test").prop("id");
```

Comment: @cjbarth `attr()` was added in 1.0, and `prop()` was added in 1.6, so I'm assuming your comment was `prop()` is the new way.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I believe, rather than old way and new way, it depends whether you are interested in the original output when the page loaded (`attr`) or that potentially modified by script (`prop`). If you aren't actually modifying the `id` attribute of any element using client side script, then `prop` and `attr` are identical.

Answer (score 23):

```
$.fn.extend({
    id : function() {
        return this.attr('id');
    }
});

alert( $('#element').id() );
```

Some checking code required of course, but easily implemented!

Answer (score 10):

If you want to get an ID of an element, let's say by a class selector, when an event (in this case click event) was fired on that specific element, then the following will do the job:

```
 $('.your-selector').click(function(){
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
 });
```

Comment: It's disappointing the best answer is this far down the page.

Answer (score 9):

`.id` is not a valid jquery function. You need to use the `.attr()` function to access attributes an element possesses. You can use `.attr()` to both change an attribute value by specifying two parameters, or get the value by specifying one.

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 7):

`$('#test').attr('id')`
In your example:

```
<div id="test"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($('#test').attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 7):

```js
    $("#button").click(function() {
      var clickID = $("#testDiv").attr("id");
      console.log(clickID)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="testDiv"> When button will click you'll get this id value </div>
<button id="button"> Button </button>
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32478456)

Answer (score 6):

Well, seems there has not been a solution and would like to propose my own solution that is an expansion of the JQuery prototype's.  I put this in a Helper file that is loaded after the JQuery library, hence the check for `window.jQuery`

```
if (window.jQuery) {
    $.prototype.id = function () {
        if (this.length > 1) {
            var val = [];
            this.each(function (idx, el) {
                val.push($(el).id());
            });
            return val;
        } else {
            return this.attr('id');
        }
    }
}
```

It may not be perfect but it is a start to maybe getting inclusion into the JQuery library.

Returns either a single string value or an Array of string values.  The Array of string values, is for the event an multi-element selector was used.

Comment: Yes and essentially what I ended up doing. I used "$.fn.id = function() { ... }", but the result seems identical to yours: jqelement.id() = "...". Is "prototype" preferred over "fn"?

Comment: @horace it guess it depends on your preference....as well, framework changes over time, so prototype may be an antique usage compared to current usage.

Answer (score 4):

`$('#test')` returns a jQuery object, so you can't use simply `object.id` to get its `Id`

you need to use `$('#test').attr('id')`, which returns your required `ID` of the element

This can also be done as follows ,

`$('#test').get(0).id` which is equal to `document.getElementById('test').id`

Comment: .. and also `$('#test')[0].id` which is the same as `.get(0)`

Answer (score 3):

```
$('tagname').attr('id');
```

Using above code you can get id.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe useful for others that find this thread. The code below will only work if you already use jQuery. The function returns always an identifier. If the element doesn't have an identifier the function generates the identifier and append this to the element.

```
var generatedIdCounter = 0;

$.fn.id = function() {
    var identifier = this.attr('id');

    if(!identifier) {
        generatedIdCounter++;
        identifier = 'isGenerated_' + generatedIdCounter;

        this.attr('id', identifier);
    }

    return identifier;
}
```

How to use:

```
$('.classname').id();

$('#elementId').id();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, **but as of 2015** this may actually work:

```
$('#test').id;
```

And you can also make assignments:

```
$('#test').id = "abc";
```

As long as you define the following JQuery plugin:

```
Object.defineProperty($.fn, 'id', {
    get: function () { return this.attr("id"); },
    set: function (newValue) { this.attr("id", newValue); }
});
```

Interestingly, if `element` is a DOM element, then:

```
element.id === $(element).id; // Is true!
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the **id** is an attribute, you can get it by using the `attr` method.

Answer (score 0):

This can be element id , class , or automatically using even

```
------------------------
$(this).attr('id');
=========================
------------------------
$("a.remove[data-id='2']").attr('id');
=========================
------------------------
$("#abc1'").attr('id');
=========================
```

Answer (score 0):

This will finally solve your problems:

lets say you have many buttons on a page and you want to change one of them with jQuery Ajax (or not ajax) depending on their ID.

lets also say that you have many different type of buttons (for forms, for approval and for like purposes), and you want the jQuery to treat only the "like" buttons.

here is a code that is working:
the jQuery will treat only the buttons that are of class .cls-hlpb,
it will take the id of the button that was clicked 
and will change it according to the data that comes from the ajax.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".clshlpbtn").on('click',function(e){
var id = $(e.target).attr('id');
 alert("The id of the button that was clicked: "+id);
$.post("demo_test_post.asp",
    {
      name: "Donald Duck",
      city: "Duckburg"
    },
    function(data,status){

    //parsing the data should come here:
    //var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    //$("#"+id).val(obj.name);
    //etc.

    if (id=="btnhlp-1")
       $("#"+id).attr("style","color:red");
    $("#"+id).val(data);
    });
});




});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" class="clshlpbtn" id="btnhlp-1" value="first btn">    </input>
<br />
<input type="button" class="clshlpbtn" id="btnhlp-2" value="second btn">    </input>
<br />
<input type="button" class="clshlpbtn" id="btnhlp-9" value="ninth btn">    </input>

</body>
</html>
```

code was taken from w3schools and changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<?php
    // include Database connection file 
    include("db_connection.php");

    // Design initial table header 
    $data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <tr>
                            <th>No.</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Email Address</th>
                            <th>Update</th>
                            <th>Delete</th>
                        </tr>';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
    if (!$result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
        exit(mysqli_error($con));
    }
    // if query results contains rows then featch those rows 
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $number = 1;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $data .= '<tr>
                <td>'.$number.'</td>
                <td>'.$row['first_name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['last_name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['email'].'</td>
                    <td><button onclick="DeleteUser('.$row['id'].')" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>';
            $number++;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        // records now found 
        $data .= '<tr><td colspan="6">Records not found!</td></tr>';
    }

    $data .= '</table>';
    echo $data;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function DeleteUser(id) {
    var conf = confirm("Are you sure, do you really want to delete User?");
    if (conf == true) {
        $.ajax({
                    url:'deleteUser.php',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{
                        id:id
                    },
            success:function(data){
                      alert('delete successfully');
                   }




}
});

deleteUser.php

<?php
// check request
if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['id']) != "")
{
    // include Database connection file
    include("db_connection.php");

    // get user id
    $user_id = $_POST['id'];

    // delete User
    $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id'";
    if (!$result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
        exit(mysqli_error($con));
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

it does not answer the OP, but may be interesting to others: you can access the `.id` field in this case:

```
$('#drop-insert').map((i, o) => o.id)
```

Comment: I'm grateful to downvoters when they explain what's wrong in my understanding.  otherwise I find them as interesting as a mosquito.

Answer (score -1):

Important: if you are creating a new object with jQuery and binding an event, you **MUST** use *prop* and not *attr*, like this:

`$("<div/>",{ id: "yourId", class: "yourClass", html: "<span></span>" }).on("click", function(e) { alert($(this).prop("id")); }).appendTo("#something");`