# Retrieve ID attr from div tags created 'on the fly'- $("<div/>" and use them in their click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating div tags on the fly inside a for loop.
The divs are outputted nicely like a chess table and there is a unique id for each. 
I just don't know how to retrieve it in its click function. 'this.id' or $(this).id doesn't work (I generally use it in $.each methods).

***How could I retrieve/refer to the id inside the click function ? ***

I've posted a bigger code part width variables, but the main part is this:

```
$("<div/>", {
    class: gridClass,
    id: cardID,
    click: function(e) {
        alert(this.id);
    }
});
```

more from the code:

```
var init = function() {
    //variable declaration
    var GRID_WIDTH = 2,
        GRID_HEIGHT = 2,
    var FACE_DOWN = 0;

    var cont = $("<div/>", {
        id: 'container'
    });

    var c1 = "card";
    var c2 = "card cardfirstInRow";
    var gridClass = "";
    var cardID = "";
    // end variable declaration

    // creating DIV-s on the fly
    for (var x = 0; x < GRID_WIDTH; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < GRID_HEIGHT; y++) {
            y === 0 ? gridClass = 'card cardfirstInRow' : gridClass = 'card';
            cardID = controller.getCardID(); //returns a unique number converted to string

            $("<div/>", {
                class: gridClass,
                id: cardID,
                click: function(e) {
                    alert(this.id);
                }
            }).appendTo(cont);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the ID of an element using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239598/how-can-i-get-the-id-of-an-element-using-jquery)

Comment: `$('<div></div>').addClass(gridClass).attr('id', cardID).on('click', function(ev) { alert(this.id) });`

Comment: Who the heck voted down on all correct answers ?! a troll !

Comment: You are right, that is a good solution. I used a different way of declaring the div with {} notation, as a result this was pointing to the Global Execution context - window. This was shown  when I debugged the code. So I can rearrange my code like you recommended, or I have just chosen a third solution click: function(e) {                     alert(e.target.id); I might run into problems with it latter, than I can still choose this solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`e.target` gives you the element (javascript object)

To get the id just use

```
var elemId = e.target.id;
```

Comment: Thank you ! You have delivered the solution !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your click function, not your creation of the div function. Because you are adding the div's to the DOM you need to use event delegation to capture the click event when it bubbles up -

```
$('body').on('click', 'div' function() {
    console.log( this.id );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

`$(this).attr('id');`

that is the method that returns an attribute value of an element using jQuery

[Here is the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/mhe9A/)

Comment: I added values of the div attributes with an object {} notation,the click event was also inside, as a result 'this' was pointing to the Global Execution context - window. This was shown  when I debugged the code. There are several ways to solve the problem (as most of the time), see the first comment and the right answer.