# How to find a id of a element that autogenerates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

How do I find a element Id that is autogenerated which means that element will never have the same id once the browser reloads.

There's a way where I find that element string let's say "Click" by doing this in jquery:

```
$( "a:contains('Click')" ); which gives me this,

<a href="test.com" id=alwayschanging >Click</a>
```

How do I send a click event to that id or string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the ID of an element using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239598/how-can-i-get-the-id-of-an-element-using-jquery)

Comment: Please decide whether your question is "How do I find a element Id that is autogenerated" or "How do I send a click event to that id or string?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a selector which doesn't make use of the ID

```
$('a[href="saveFile"]').click()
```

If you can't use jQuery you will have to use

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
    var el = els[i];
    if (el.text === 'Click') {
        el.click()
    }
}
```

Comment: it's really not a link to another website, it's a file once click you can save it.

Comment: Could you post the tag with its attributes?

Comment: <a href="savefile" id="saveIt">Click</a>

Comment: I thought you said the ID was autogenerated?

Comment: If you can add a unique class to the tag I would recommend using `$('a.unique_class').click()`

Comment: it is autogenerated, I dont' know what the next ID is going to look like, that's why I'm wondering how to do it,  $("a:contains('Click')" ).attr('id'); this gives me the current ID of the link but IE browser doesn't like jquery for some reason that's why i need to find another way to do it

Comment: @TheKid What version of jQuery are you using? 2.x drops IE support, but <2 should be fine.

Comment: If you really can't use jQuery use could use `document.getElementByTag("a").getElementsByClass("unique_class").click();`

Comment: How do you know which version of jQuery you are using?

Comment: @OhAuth the link does not have unique class, only id.

Comment: @TheKid check the version number in the script tag, where you include it.

Comment: @TheKid Then use `console.log($.fn.jquery)`

Comment: huh? use what?  it says "2.1.1" my IE must not support JQUERY URG

Comment: I need to find a way to figure out what that autogenerated ID will be each time so that I can programmatically click on it using document.getById("id").click();

Comment: @TheKid You have two options, find a selector which works or catch the ID server side. If the item is nested in an item with a unique ID you can use the CSS 'child of' operator `>`, read more here https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/.

Comment: Can't i just find the tag "<A> that has the string title "Click" and click on it?

Comment: @TheKid text selectors are not part of the CSS specification so there is no clean native JS way of doing it but you should be able to use the solution in my answer edit.

Comment: Ok, that works thanks, so once it has clicked, i get the save dialog, how would i go about clicking the save button on that dialog? or just clicking the "Enter" key to automatically save it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `id` to send a click event. Just click it

```
$( "a:contains('Click')" ).click()
```

Comment: that don't work. it only shows me the object information ect.

Comment: Did you put any parameters inside the call to **click()**?

Comment: No. I did not but that shouldn't matter.