# referencing the id of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to reference the `id` of a div-table row in the variable `thisId`. When I `console.log(thisId)`, it says that `thisId` is `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('.deleteButton').click(function(){
    var thisId = $(this).parent().parent().id;
    for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
        if (tableData[i].rowValue === thisId) {
            tableData.splice(thisId, 1);
        }
    }
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
}
}
```

HTML

```
"<div id='" + tableData[i].rowValue + "' class=\"Row\">" +
                            "<div class=\"Cell\">" +
                            "<p>" + tableData[i].textInput + "</p>" +
                        "</div>" +
                        "<div class=\"Cell\">" +
                            "<p>" + tableData[i].perIntervalInput + "</p>" +
                        "</div>" +
                        "<div class=\"Cell\">" +
                            "<p>" + tableData[i].radioInput + "</p>" +
                        "</div>" +
                        "<div class=\"Cell\">" +
                            "<button class=\"deleteButton\">Delete</button>" +
                        "</div>" +
                        "</div>"
```

Comment: Where's the HTML that this would reference?

Comment: `.id` is a property on DOM Elements, not jQuery.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239598/how-can-i-get-the-id-of-an-element-using-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239598/how-can-i-get-the-id-of-an-element-using-jquery)

Comment: .attr or .prop didn't seem to help my issue

Comment: Why not just `$(this).closest('[id]').remove();`? Why do you need to 'reference' ID? What is exactly your expected behaviour?

Comment: I already have the div removal covered (`$(this).parent().parent().remove();` works fine), I'm trying to reference the ID so I can remove the object in my array that corresponds with the div.

Comment: @germz So `var thisId = $(this).closest('[id]')[0].id;` or `var thisId = $(this).closest('[id]').attr('id');` or whatever but your question is still unclear

Comment: I need the ID because it is the same as the rowValue property in an array object that corresponds with the row. I need to remove that object when .deletebutton is clicked. I realize that my method for that is wrong, but right now I'm just trying to figure out how to actually get the ID of the parenting row div.

Answer (score 5):

ID is an attribute and so can be reference via the [`attr(..)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function.

```
var thisId = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
```

Comment: attempted .attr as well, same result.

Comment: As others have mentioned, you need to expand on your question. We need to see the HTML that you are working with and how it refers to your JS.

Comment: Just added the html (it's messy looking because it's being appended)

Comment: If the above code still doesn't work it seems there must be something else going wrong with your script. As a check, try `console.log($(this).parent().parent().get(0).outerHTML);` and see if it is actually the code you expect it to be.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery, you can use:

```
var thisId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
```

But your HTML isn't here to show us what you're actually referencing, and whether you're referencing it properly, so there might be something else in play.