# jQuery clicking function - get ID of this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've written my own jQuery clicking function, but for an unkown reason, it doesn't work. I get error on *line 4*.

```
for (var i = 1;i<=3;i++){
    $("#Block"+i).click(function(){
        $(this).effect("shake", function(){
            if (this == "#Block3"){
                window.open('contact.html','blank');//open link link in a new page
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 4):

### Explanation

`this` on line 4 returns (or is) an object, it is a [DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) (such as `<div>` or something like that) You **can't** compare object `this` and string `"#Block3"`.

These two things are very different. It is like comparing pears and apples.

Take a look at [JavaScript Data Types](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp) I think, it could help you.

### Documentation

See the documentation of [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) object.

Getting ID of an element [How can I get the ID of an element using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239598/how-can-i-get-the-id-of-an-element-using-jquery)

### Edit of your code

You have to get the **ID** of the object (*this*) and then compare it with the string *"Block3"*

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    $("#Block" + i).click(function() {
        $(this).effect("shake", function() {
            if (this.id == "Block3") {
                window.open('contact.html', 'blank'); //open link link in a new page
            }
        });
    });
}
```

### Edit of your code 2

jQuery is here to help you to do less of code. Take a while to look at some tutorials.

Your code could be shortened to something like this

```js
$('.blocks-container').on('click', '.block', function() {
  $(this).effect('shake', function() {
    if (this.id == 'Block3')
      window.open('contact.html', 'blank'); //open link link in a new page
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blocks-container">
  <div id="Block1" class="block">Block1</div>
  <div id="Block2" class="block">Block2</div>
  <div id="Block3" class="block">Block3</div>
  <div id="Block4" class="block">Block4</div>
  <div id="Block5" class="block">Block5</div>
</div>
```

With **unlimited** number of "Blocks". [See Rory's answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38285422/jquery-clicking-function/38285450#38285450)

#### .click vs .on

Also please learn to use

```
$('.blocks-container').on('click', '.block', function() {});
```

Instead of

```
$('.block').click(function() {});
```

Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click) I think, that you will understand later.

### Edit of your code 3

Or you can base your function on "Block" div **index** *(= number of place under the parent element)* instead of index. So you don't have to use **ID** for each of blocks.

```js
$('.blocks-container').on('click', '.block', function() {
  $(this).effect('shake', function() {
    if ($(this).index('.block') == 2)
      window.open('contact.html', 'blank'); //open link link in a new page
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blocks-container">
  <div class="block">Block1</div>
  <div class="block">Block2</div>
  <div class="block">Block3</div>
  <div class="block">Block4</div>
  <div class="block">Block5</div>
</div>
```

**Love jQuery. Peace!**

Comment: @sapir-sosnovsky if I helped you, please accept my answer. thanks

Answer (score 2):

`this` in your code is a DOMElement. When coerced to a string it will never match `#Block3`, hence your `if` condition never hits.

Assuming you're trying to match the `id` of a specific element, then you just need to compare against the `id` property of `this`:

```
(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
    $("#Block" + i).click(function(){
        $(this).effect("shake", function(){
            if (this.id === "Block3") {
                window.open('contact.html', 'blank');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Also note that it would be *much* better practice to put a common class on all the `#BlockX` elements and use a single event handler on all of them:

```js
$('.block').click(function() {
  $(this).effect("shake", function(){
    if (this.id === 'Block3')
      alert('you clicked block3!');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="Block1" class="block">Block1</div>
<div id="Block2" class="block">Block2</div>
<div id="Block3" class="block">Block3</div>
<div id="Block4" class="block">Block4</div>
<div id="Block5" class="block">Block5</div>
```