# how to find the div id on mouse click in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have multiple div in a webform and when i clicked on a particular div i need to perform some task based on the div id.

Is there any way to find the div id on mouse click?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="firstdiv">div1</div>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div id="seconddiv">div2</div>
    <td>
    <td>
       <div id="thriddiv">div3</div>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div id="fourthdiv">div4</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: use `$(this).attr('id')` inside click event it will get the id of div

Comment: check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6jLm8kvs/)

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```
$("table div").click(function() {
    var divID = this.id;//Or $(this).attr("id");
    //Your code here 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('div').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="firstdiv">div1</div>


      <td>
        <td>
          <div id="seconddiv">div2</div>
          <td>
            <td>
              <div id="thriddiv">div3</div>
              <td>
                <td>
                  <div id="fourthdiv">div4</div>
                  <td>
                    <tr>
                      <table>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Bind `click` event over `div` element
- `this` refers to clicked element in `click-handler`
- Access `id` property of the `element`

```js
$('table div').on('click', function() {
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="firstdiv">div1</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="seconddiv">div2</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="thriddiv">div3</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="fourthdiv">div4</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform a function at the time to click on div, calling from the ID, this is the code:

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#firstdiv').click(function(){

    /*I add alert for the example, but here is where you put your code*/
     alert($(this).attr('id'));

});

</head>

<body>

<div id="firstdiv">div1</div>

</body>
```

In addition this is the information link with the function click () in jquery, has example of how to use it in different event on an element: https://api.jquery.com/click/

example calling the div inside table:

```
$("table div").click(function(){

   /*I add alert for the example, but here is where you put your code*/
   alert($(this).attr('id'));

});
```

Example calling with the tag div:

```
$('div').click(function() {

  /*I add alert for the example, but here is where you put your code*/
  alert($(this).attr('id'));

});
```

--body

```
<table>

<tr>

<td><div id="demo1"></td>

</tr>

</table>
```

And this is a post with good example:[How can I get the ID of an element using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239598/how-can-i-get-the-id-of-an-element-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple yet effective answer

```
<div id="someId" onclick="somefunction(this.id)">
   Click me
</div>
<script>
  function somefunction(id){
    alert(id);
  }
</script>
```