# How to get value of id in an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

tried getting value of attributes. I can get values of other attributes but not the id. Here is my jquery code. While i can get the value of class, the value of id is either undefined or null.

```
$(".someClass").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var class = this.className;

    alert(title);
    alert(class);       
});
```

Thanks

Comment: an jsfiddle please ?

Comment: Add your HTML code

Comment: Where is the `title` variable set? shouldn't you `alert` the `id` variable instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239598/how-can-i-get-the-id-of-an-element-using-jquery

Comment: keyword class is reserved. rest is fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your faults:

1- **class** is a reserved word. use another word.

2- You are not alerting the **id**

```
$(".someClass").click(function(){
    var myId = $(this).attr("id");
    var myClass = this.className;

    alert(myId);
    alert(myClass);       
});
```

Let's have a sample:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".someClass").click(function(){
    var myId = $(this).attr("id");
    var myClass = this.className;

    alert(myId);
    alert(myClass);       
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="someClass" id='someId'>Click Me</div>
```

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki, seriously, I wish the downvoter explained why

Comment: I am getting "undefined".

Comment: @user3750366, I updated my answer with the snippet. If you are getting 'undefined' please make a fiddle and put it here to be able debug it

Comment: @user3750366, you forgot to attach the jquery library. try this: https://jsfiddle.net/tL0oLtu6/1/

Comment: Yes, now it works. Thanks dude. I'll try it one me original code and see

Comment: here is the updated  jsfiddle. can you check why this is not working here https://jsfiddle.net/tL0oLtu6/2/

Comment: @user3750366, because the elements you are clicking, don't have id.

Comment: yes, that is correct. i m sry about that. wasted so much time

Comment: @user3750366, That's OK. If you got your answer, please check it as the correct answer, to prevent more developers spending time on this post.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using attr("id"), use prop("id")

Comment: yazsid, why do you think that is required?

Comment: Because of experience in other projects and also because of this answer:

Comment: While your answer might be correct, you'd be best to expand it to explain why and how that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d1amzfLx/3/)

```
$(".someClass").click(function(){ 
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var cls = this.className; 
    alert(id);
    alert(cls);
});
```