# Checking Id of clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several images with the same class and would like to set up a click function that changes the text in some elements based on which image is clicked.
My if statement is not working, I'm not entirely sure why because I've used this method before, or so I thought.

```
$('.gallery_image').click(function(e) {
    var t = $(this);
    if(t.id == 'csf') {
        console.log('It works!');
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4qdh47ck/)

Comment: if(t[0].id == 'csf')... t is jQuery object, and it doesn't have id property...https://jsfiddle.net/4qdh47ck/1/ console.log t to see why this works....

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3239600/831645

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `t.attr('id')` instead of `t.id`

[More about .attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: Or use `if(this.id == 'csf')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution is using classes instead of id's. Call the click function on the class they share then use a second class to distinguish them with the hasClass function:

```
 <div id="csf" class="gallery_image csf">csf</div>
<div id="csi" class="gallery_image csi">csi</div>

    $('.gallery_image').click(function(e) {
    var t = $(this);
    if(t.hasClass('csf')) {
        alert("It works!");
    }

     else if(t.hasClass('csi')) {
        alert("So does this!");
    }
});
```