# Remove seen notifications based on scrolling using Jquery/Javascript/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I have to clear/remove notification based on user scrolling means clear the notification if user has seen it. It's a pop-up window for notification. The seen notification should be cleared/removed only after user close the pop-up notification window. I am new to Javascript/jQuery, so confused how to do it.
Here is my code.

```
<div class="notifications" id="notifications">
   <p class="notif" id="1"> First notification <span id='time1'></span></p>
   <p class="notif" id="2"> Second notification <span id='time2'></span></p>
   <p class="notif" id="3"> Third notification <span id='time3'></span></p>
   <p class="notif" id="4"> Fourth notification <span id='time4'></span></p>
   <p class="notif" id="5"> Fifth notification <span id='time5'></span></p>
   <p class="notif" id="6"> Sixth notification <span id='time6'></span></p>
</div>
<script>
   jQuery(function($) {
      $('#notifications').on("scroll", function() {             
         $('.notif').each(function () {
            if( $(this).next().offset() ) {
               console.log("current: " + $(this).offset().top);
               console.log("next: " + $(this).next().offset().top);
               if( $(this).offset().top <= $(this).next().offset().top ) {
                  $(this).find( ".notif" ).css( "color", "red" );
                  //return;
               }
            }
         });
      });
   });
</script>
```

In console log, it displays current and next pos value and then it displays error: TypeError: $(...).next(...).offset(...) is undefined

I am also confuse how to clear/remove the seen notification after user close the pop-up notification window.

Comment: check if `$(this).next()` exist .last element has no next elements

Comment: thank you.  I have edited the code. Error is gone but still it's not changing the font color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change `$(this).find( ".notif" ).css( "color", "red" );` to 
    `$(this).css( "color", "red" );` . `this` is already `.notif`.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
         $('#notifications').on("scroll", function() {       
         $('.notif').each(function () {
            if( $(this).next().offset() ) {
               console.log("current: " + $(this).offset().top);
               console.log("next: " + $(this).next().offset().top);
               if( $(this).offset().top <= 50)  {
                  $(this).css( "color", "red" );
                  //return;
               } else {
                 $(this).css( "color", "black" );
               }
            }
         });
      });
   });
```

```css
#notifications {
  overflow:scroll;
  height:140px;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="notifications" id="notifications">
   <p class="notif"> First notification </p>
   <p class="notif"> Second notification </p>
   <p class="notif"> Third notification </p>
   <p class="notif"> Fourth notification </p>
   <p class="notif"> Fifth notification </p>
   <p class="notif"> Sixth notification </p>
   <p class="notif"> Seventh notification </p>
   <p class="notif"> Eighth notification </p>
   <p class="notif"> Ninth notification </p>
   <p class="notif"> Tenth notification </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but this code changes color for all notifications. I need to change the color of the notifications one by one as user scroll down the pop-up window.

Comment: Then, you need to change below.

`if( $(this).offset().top <= $(this).next().offset().top ) {
                  $(this).css( "color", "red" );
                  //return;
               }`

Every `$(this)` is higher than `$(this).next()` so css is changed.

Comment: I edited code as you say,  `if( $(this).offset().top <= 50)  {
                  $(this).css( "color", "red" );
                  //return;
               } else {
                 $(this).css( "color", "black" );
               }` Added.

Comment: thank you. It's not working for the notifications at the bottom of the pop-up window. Suppose, If there are 20 notifications, its only changing color for first 10. I think the reason is that scrollbar is smaller. Also, how come $(this).offset().top is less than 50?

Comment: 50 is just random value for example. Not special meaning. You can adjust value or add condition for your purpose.

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question. Is there any way to send id to javascript function inside div? In the code, I am calling displayTime( "12/12/2017", this.id); function. I need to pass date of notification and current element id but I can't get the id. Is there any way to send the current element id?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239598/how-can-i-get-the-id-of-an-element-using-jquery
This may helpful for you.
`$(this).attr('id')` returns id.