# Alert shows [object Object]?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to alert an id but it shows `[object Object]`. How to get an ID?

```
$('.x3').click(function() {
  var id = $(this.id);
  alert(id);
});
```

Comment: try either `var id = this.id` or `var id $(this).attr("id")`

Comment: what is x3? share HTML

Comment: Or just try to `console.log(id)` and see it on your dev console without changing any line of you code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the ID of an element using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239598/how-can-i-get-the-id-of-an-element-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this)` is an `DOM element`. Try to access the `attr` property of the element.

```
$('.x3').click(function(){
     var id = $(this).attr("id");
     alert(id);
);
```

Comment: What do you mean, "Dom element, not an object"? Every DOM element is an object.

Comment: `this` is a DOM element. `$(this)[0]` is a DOM element. `$(this)` is NOT a DOM element but a jQuery object. [See more](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @Hikarunomemory, any way the answer was updated after Amadan comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
var id = $(this.id);
```

This statement simply returns a jQuery wrapper object (with `length` 0 if there is no matching element exists on DOM).

Stringifying it to show it on `alert` will print `[object Object]`. You rather meant to use

```
var id = this.id; // or var id = $(this).attr('id')
```