# Javascript add a variable from div id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

I have written a page that utilizes jquery draggable. It effectively has about 160 div elements that can be dragged around a page to allocate "stall sites" for an upcoming fete. To deal with so many elements I have a small database table that has 4 columns, those being ID, LEFT, TOP and DETAILS
Each Div has id="ID",  and the Content="Details"
The first 2 of 160+ lines generated by PHP and SQL look like

```
div class="drag" id="1" style="left: 10px; top: 10px;">FS01<ul><li class="posX"><li class="posY">div>
div class="drag" id="2" style="left: 60px; top: 10px;">FS01<ul><li class="posX"><li class="posY">div>
```

After the elements have been dragged I find their new positions with the following Javascript

```
drag: function(){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var xPos = offset.left;
    var yPos = offset.top;
    //var zID = " <?php echo $id ?> "; //This is what I want to do
    $('.posX', this).text('x: ' + xPos);
    $('.posY', this).text('y: ' + yPos);
}
```

What I can't do (and a Javascript person could do this in seconds) is grab the ID and turn it into a Jquery variable (let's call it zID). With a new ID, LEFT and TOP, I can feed them back into an updating PHP File to make the new positions persistent. I've got the database, the PHP, the HTML, the Jquery running draggable and retrieving the "new" positions (xPos & yPos) and the PHP/SQL to return them to the database, but what I cant do is tie the positions to the ID ... HELP PLEASE!!

Comment: `this` is the element you want the `id` from. Just use its properties.

Comment: More specifically, `let zID = $(this).attr('id');` might do the trick for you.

Comment: @Exfridos There's abolutely no need for jQuery in this case... Just: `this.id`

Answer (score 0):

this is the line of code you are searching for

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

see this link for more info

[How can I get the ID of an element using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239598/how-can-i-get-the-id-of-an-element-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys,
I had already tried $(this).attr('id') but I did what the answer suggested and hadnt included a semi colon at the end. Such a basic mistake.
All good... all working
gri2a

Answer (score 0):

For other readers I should include the full answer which is-

```
   drag: function(){
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var xPos = offset.left;
        var yPos = offset.top;
        var zId = $(this).attr('id');//my new variable
        $('.posX', this).text('x: ' + xPos);
        $('.posY', this).text('y: ' + yPos);
        $('.Id', this).text('z: ' + zId);//text to display zId
    }
```